# How can I allow users to send emails through my django app but coming from their own gmail account?

Tags: django, gmail, gmail-api

I have a django app where users can send emails through the app to contacts that they upload themselves. I use Sendgrid to send the email and the recipient receives an email from a "white-label" address like hello@mydomain.com

Now, I would like to implement a system where I can allow users to send emails through our app but that those emails are sent by their own email address. To make it simple, let's just consider "Gmail" and if a user want they can "login with their gmail account" on my app and then send emails from my app that are sent from their account... I know that Gmail has an API and I wonder if I can leverage it to do what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely send emails using Gmail API methods but keep in mind the below stated in their [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides):

> Note: The Gmail API shouldn't be used to replace IMAP for developing a
> full-fledged email client. Instead, see IMAP, POP, and SMTP.

As they recommend, you could integrate [IMAP/SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp) features in your application so users can authenticate/provide access to their accounts and achieve your goal of having emails sent from their accounts.

Comment: Oh nice, that's awesome! Do you know if to do this the user needs to also manually do something on their gmail account settings OR if all the necessary credentials can be asked/triggered through a form on my application (that triggers an api call to google)?

Comment: Users need to enable this feature called ```Less Secure Apps``` which is being disabled for only Gmail.com accounts (pending for Google Workspace Accounts) see documentation [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255). Google Basically is disabling that in favor to [Google OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2) so instead of going through the hassle of having the user configure their accounts for access, OAuth can be implemented so it is more convenient.